# how to negate a kibana (elastic) apm query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm, elastic-apm

I actually use ELK stack (7.17.8)
I use the APM feature with python/flask integration.

I actually can't figure how to make negation filter working with APM.

I try to filter all non-POST transactions with this apm filter:

`NOT http.request.method:POST`

The documentation is clear about how to achieve this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.6/kuery-query.html#_negating_a_query

The kibana UI displays me GET, DELETE... AND POST transactions

When I click on the GET transactions everything is fine (I see traces etc...)

When I click on a POST transactions (which are not supposed to be in the list because of the filter), I have the message "The selected trace cannot be found"

Is there something I miss in the APM usage, the filter feature or something else?

Comment: to be really sure: does the "http.request.method" field exist?

Comment: Yes the property exists